# Python saving data to a csv file

Tags: python, function, csv

I normally use txt files but i need to use a csv i based this off how i do txt files and i am not sure what i am doing wrong can anyone help me please.

```
Home = "Road"
House = 5

def Save(Home,House):
    Saved=open('Saved.csv', 'a')
    Saved.write(Home+House+"/n")
    Saved.close()

Save(Home,House)
```

I get this error

```
File "F:/Pygame/Test12.py", line 74, in Save
     Saved.write(Home+House+"/n")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: …what are you trying to do? What should `Home+House+"/n"` give? (Also, you're using a forward slash. I'm guessing that should be a backslash.) Where does CSV come in here? I don't see any evidence of it. If you're trying to read or write CSV files you should be using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) that's not a `.csv` file.

2) in python, you cannot concatenate integers with strings without prior conversion.

3) doing this: `Home+str(House)` would be legal, but when you want to read back your file you have to separate both fields (you provided no way of separating them)

Here's a code which would create a *real* csv file:

```
import csv
def Save(Home,House):
    with open('Saved.csv', 'a') as Saved:
       cw = csv.writer(Saved)
       cw.writerow([Home,House])
```

when you compose your row, you can put any data you want, the `csv` module will convert it to string if needed.

BTW to read it back, use a `csv.reader` and iterate through the rows. Since you know the datatype, you can convert 2nd column to `int` directly.

```
with open('Saved.csv', 'r') as Saved:
   cr = csv.reader(Saved)
   for row in cr:
       Home = row[0]
       House = int(row[1])
       # now you have to do something with those variables :)
```

Comment: so if i wanted to read the home and the house from the csv file how would i do it properly

Answer (score 2):

You can not concatenate an integer with a string, use the following to convert the int to string:

```
Saved.write(Home + str(House) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python variables have types.  So you are trying to add 5 to the 'House' which is not defined application.  To make this work you have to convert number 5 to string '5'.  As ettanany suggest use

```
Saved.write(Home+str(House)+"\n")
```

Also,  note that it's  '\n' not '/n'